# INT Column value scrambled beyond 10 characters

Tags: mysql, sql, database, drupal, phpmyadmin

I'm creating a table with column of INT(20). Whenever I submit a value greater than 10 characters, the value is scrambled. Anything 10 or less characters as the value is stored properly, and I'm not sure why. I've set the length to 20, yet it seems to be ignoring this.

[Char length +10]
Ex: ( 1234567890123 ---**becomes**---> 2147483647 )

[Char length <= 10]
Ex: ( 1234567890 ---*remains*---> 1234567890 )

I'm thinking I may need to changed the structure of the table somehow, but so far nothing has worked. I'd appreciate any helpful words of wisdom to get my numeric values greater than 10 stored properly in my table.

Thanks.

Note: I'm using MySQL, PhpMyAdmin, Drupal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's overflowing.

The maximum value of an `INT` is 2147483647. You should use a `BIGINT` instead of `INT`.

```
                 size    min                         max
INT              4       -2147483648                 2147483647
UNSIGNED INT     4       0                           4294967295
BIGINT           8       -9223372036854775808        9223372036854775807
UNSIGNED BIGINT  8       0                           18446744073709551615
```

See the documentation:

- [Integer Types (Exact Value) - INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html)

Answer (score 1):

`INT(20)` just means that 20 numbers may be displayed. This acts as a cut-off if the number is bigger, or a pad size when `ZEROFILL` is specified.

Since the biggest integer that can be stored is 2<sup>32</sup>-1 (assuming `UNSIGNED`), and you are exceeding that value, you get "scrambled" numbers.

To solve this issue, use `BIGINT`, which allows you to go up to 2<sup>64</sup>-1, or `FLOAT` to get the potential for humongous numbers at the cost of some precision.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!  =)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should be using DECIMAL rather than INT or BIGINT.  This is the data type in SQL designed to hold numbers with specified precision, which is what you seem to have.